# Is there a list of most popular CLI commands for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cli

I am looking for a quick, easy reference for the most popular CLI commands and how they are used in Magento 2.

Answer (score 8):

enter magento root via CLI

compile & deploy when adding/changing modules, adjust language(s) as needed

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module Vendor_Module2
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=1024M bin/magento setup:di:compile
rm -rf var/di var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_CA xx_XX
```

clear out cache, pub, var & reindex, as needed

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf var/di var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed pub/static/*
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

adjust deploy mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

deploy sample data

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

set permissions after deploy

```
find ~/magentoroot/pub -type f -exec chmod 644 -R {} \;
find ~/magentoroot/pub -type d -exec chmod 755 -R {} \;
```

upgrade via composer

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
composer update
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a list of magento 2 commands:

```
Magento CLI version 2.0.4

Usage:
 command [options] [arguments]

Options:
 --help (-h)           Display this help message
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version
 --ansi                Force ANSI output
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question

Available commands:
 help                                      Displays help for a command
 list                                      Lists commands
admin
 admin:user:create                         Creates an administrator
 admin:user:unlock                         Unlock Admin Account
cache
 cache:clean                               Cleans cache type(s)
 cache:disable                             Disables cache type(s)
 cache:enable                              Enables cache type(s)
 cache:flush                               Flushes cache storage used by cache type(s)
 cache:status                              Checks cache status
catalog
 catalog:images:resize                     Creates resized product images
cron
 cron:run                                  Runs jobs by schedule
customer
 customer:hash:upgrade                     Upgrade customer's hash according to the latest algorithm
deploy
 deploy:mode:set                           Set application mode.
 deploy:mode:show                          Displays current application mode.
dev
 dev:source-theme:deploy                   Collects and publishes source files for theme.
 dev:tests:run                             Runs tests
 dev:urn-catalog:generate                  Generates the catalog of URNs to *.xsd mappings for the IDE to highlight xml.
 dev:xml:convert                           Converts XML file using XSL style sheets
i18n
 i18n:collect-phrases                      Discovers phrases in the codebase
 i18n:pack                                 Saves language package
 i18n:uninstall                            Uninstalls language packages
indexer
 indexer:info                              Shows allowed Indexers
 indexer:reindex                           Reindexes Data
 indexer:set-mode                          Sets index mode type
 indexer:show-mode                         Shows Index Mode
 indexer:status                            Shows status of Indexer
info
 info:adminuri                             Displays the Magento Admin URI
 info:backups:list                         Prints list of available backup files
 info:currency:list                        Displays the list of available currencies
 info:dependencies:show-framework          Shows number of dependencies on Magento framework
 info:dependencies:show-modules            Shows number of dependencies between modules
 info:dependencies:show-modules-circular   Shows number of circular dependencies between modules
 info:language:list                        Displays the list of available language locales
 info:timezone:list                        Displays the list of available timezones
maintenance
 maintenance:allow-ips                     Sets maintenance mode exempt IPs
 maintenance:disable                       Disables maintenance mode
 maintenance:enable                        Enables maintenance mode
 maintenance:status                        Displays maintenance mode status
module
 module:disable                            Disables specified modules
 module:enable                             Enables specified modules
 module:status                             Displays status of modules
 module:uninstall                          Uninstalls modules installed by composer
sampledata
 sampledata:deploy                         Deploy sample data modules
 sampledata:remove                         Remove all sample data packages from composer.json
 sampledata:reset                          Reset all sample data modules for re-installation
setup
 setup:backup                              Takes backup of Magento Application code base, media and database
 setup:config:set                          Creates or modifies the deployment configuration
 setup:cron:run                            Runs cron job scheduled for setup application
 setup:db-data:upgrade                     Installs and upgrades data in the DB
 setup:db-schema:upgrade                   Installs and upgrades the DB schema
 setup:db:status                           Checks if DB schema or data requires upgrade
 setup:di:compile                          Generates DI configuration and all non-existing interceptors and factories
 setup:di:compile-multi-tenant             Generates all non-existing proxies and factories, and pre-compile class definitions, inheritance information and plugin definitions
 setup:install                             Installs the Magento application
 setup:performance:generate-fixtures       Generates fixtures
 setup:rollback                            Rolls back Magento Application codebase, media and database
 setup:static-content:deploy               Deploys static view files
 setup:store-config:set                    Installs the store configuration
 setup:uninstall                           Uninstalls the Magento application
 setup:upgrade                             Upgrades the Magento application, DB data, and schema
theme
 theme:uninstall                           Uninstalls theme
```

Answer (score 4):

I just found this blog: [magento 2 useful commands list](http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/magento-2-useful-commands-list-391), but being a beginner I just rely on the official guide, as it explains when each command is needed, and the magento command list (above) can be shown in CLI using :

```
$ bin/magento list
```

Answer (score 1):

In future(Magento 2.2) release there are couple of new commands for `Magento2`, like

system config value(Very useful),

`php bin/magento config:show` : Shows configuration value for given path. If path is not specified, all saved values will be shown

`php bin/magento config:set` : Change system configuration

`php bin/magento config:sensitive:set` : Set sensitive configuration values

For app

`php bin/magento app:config:dump` : Create dump of application

`php bin/magento app:config:import` : Import data from shared configuration files to appropriate data storage

Answer (score 1):

**Setup upgrade:**

php bin/magento s:up

**Cache Flush:**

php bin/magento c:f

**Disable Cache:**

php bin/magento c:d

**Enable Cache:**

​​​​​​php bin/magento c:e

**Static Content Deploy:**

php bin/magento s:s:d

**Di Compile:**

php bin/magento s:d:c

**Var clean folder:**

php bin/magento v:c

**Uninstall Magento application:**

php bin/magento s:un

**Runs cron job scheduled for setup application:**

php bin/magento s:c:r

**Disables specified modules:**

php bin/magento mo:d CompanyName_ModuleName

**Enables specified modules:**

php bin/magento mo:e CompanyName_ModuleName

**Displays status of modules:**

php bin/magento mo:s

**Uninstalls modules installed by composer (which only installed by composer):**

php bin/magento mo:u CompanyName_ModuleName

**Cleans cache type(s):**

php bin/magento c:c

**Disables cache type(s):**

php bin/magento c:d

**Enables cache type(s):**

php bin/magento c:e

**Flushes cache storage used by cache type(s):**

php bin/magento c:f

**Checks cache status:**

php bin/magento c:s

**Enable Maintenance Mode Using Command Line:**

php bin/magento ma:e

**Disable Maintenance Mode Using Command Line:**

php bin/magento ma:d

**Shows allowed Indexers:**

php bin/magento i:i

**Reindexes Data:**

php bin/magento i:rei

**Resets indexer status to invalid:**

php bin/magento i:res

**Sets index mode type:**

php bin/magento i:res

**Shows status of Indexer:**

php bin/magento i:st

Answer (score 0):

Most useful commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento module:status
php bin/magento module:enable Modulename_HelloWorld

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/luma --theme Magento/secothe nd_theme
```

For more commands follow link.

http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/magento-2-useful-commands-list-391

Answer (score 0):

In this post you can find all usefull commands above. But I was require command script which is helpfull to frontend developer as well as client who can run magento commands without open SSH.

So, I have created one GUI script and added on GIT. Please refer below link.

https://github.com/Darshanmodi1427/Magento2_commands_script

Answer (score 0):

Enter Magento Root via CLI, and use following command according to your requirements.

**Setup Upgrade Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**If you don’t want to remove pub/static files while installing/updating database then use following command**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated

**Cache Clean Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Cache Flush Using Command Line

> php bin/magento cache:flush

**View cache status Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento cache:status

**Enable Cache Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento cache:enable [cache_type]

**Disable Cache Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento cache:disable [cache_type]

**Static Content Deploy Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**Static Content Deploy For Particular Language Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

**Static Content Deploy For Magento Backend Theme Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme="Magento/backend"

**Static Content Deploy For Specific Themes Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/luma --theme Magento/second_theme

**Exclude Themes on Static Content Deploy and does not minify HTML files Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --exclude-theme Magento/luma --no-html-minify

**Reindexing Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

**View the list of indexers Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento indexer:info

**View indexer status Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento indexer:status

**Show the mode of all indexers Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento indexer:show-mode

**See all modules Status Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento module:status

**Enable module Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Module

**Disable module Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento module:disable Namespace_Module

**Uninstall Module Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento module:uninstall Namespace_Module

**Check Current Mode Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:show

**Change To Developer Mode Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

**Change To Production Mode Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

**Run the single-tenant Compiler Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

**Unlock Admin User Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento admin:user:unlock adminusername

**Enable Maintenance Mode Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable

**To enable maintenance mode for all clients except 192.0.0.1 and 192.0.0.2**

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.0.1 --ip=192.0.0.2

**To clear the list of IPs**

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip=none

**Disable Maintenance Mode Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento maintenance:disable

**Check Maintenance Mode Status Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento maintenance:status

**Allow IP on Maintenance Mode Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento maintenance:allow-ips --ip=192.0.0.1 --ip=192.0.0.2

**Set Magento crontab Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento cron:install --force

**To view the crontab, enter the following command as the Magento file system owner**

> crontab -l

**Remove Magento crontab Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento cron:remove

Answer (score 0):

To install new extension-
php bin/magento module:enable Packagename_Modulename --clear-static-content
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod 777 -R var
chmod 777 -R pub

To clear cache -
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf var/cache/*

For reindexing -
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

**Command Shortcut for Setup Upgrade**

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

If you don’t want to remove pub/static files while installing/updating database then use the following command.

```
php bin/magento s:up --keep-generated
```

**Command Shortcut for Cache Clean**

```
php bin/magento c:c
```

**Command Shortcut for Cache Flush**

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Command Shortcut for Disable Cache**

```
php bin/magento c:d
```

**Command Shortcut for Enable Cache**

```
php bin/magento c:e
```

**Command Shortcut for Reindexing**

```
php bin/magento i:rei
```

**Command Shortcut for View the list of indexers**

```
php bin/magento i:i
```

**Command Shortcut for View indexer status**

```
php bin/magento i:st
```

**Command Shortcut for View indexer Resets**

```
php bin/magento i:res
```

**Command Shortcut for Show the mode of all indexers**

```
php bin/magento i:sh
```

**Command Shortcut for Static Content Deploy**

```
php bin/magento s:s:d
```

**Command Shortcut for Static Content Deploy For Particular Language**

```
php bin/magento s:s:d en_US
```

**Command Shortcut for Static Content Deploy For Magento Backend theme**

```
php bin/magento s:s:d --theme="Magento/backend"
```

**Command Shortcut for Static Content Deploy For Specific Themes**

```
php bin/magento s:s:d --theme Magento/luma --theme Magento/second_theme
```

**Command Shortcut for Exclude Themes on Static Content Deploy and does not minify HTML**

```
php bin/magento s:s:d en_US --exclude-theme Magento/luma --no-html-minify
```

**Command Shortcut for Di Compile**

```
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

**Command Shortcut for See all modules Status**

```
php bin/magento mo:s
```

**Command Shortcut for Enable module**

```
php bin/magento mo:e Namespace_Module
```

**Command Shortcut for Disable module**

```
php bin/magento mo:d Namespace_Module
```

**Command Shortcut for Uninstall Module**

```
php bin/magento mo:u Namespace_Module
```

**Command Shortcut for Check Current Mode**

```
php bin/magento d:m:sh
```

**Command Shortcut for Change To Developer Mode**

```
php bin/magento d:m:se developer
```

**Command Shortcut for Change To Production Mode**

```
php bin/magento d:m:se production
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Magento 2 Useful CLI Command list

http://magelara.com/magento-2-useful-commands-list/