# Magento2 bin/console commands returned empty

Tags: magento2, cli

I'm wroking with Magento 2.1.1 (with PHP 5.6) and when I try to run a bin/magento command I'm getting nothing.
No error, no message, nothing.

I didn't found any special message on logs.
Has anyone seen this problem before? There's some recomendation to try to debug this issue?

Comment: Barbanet, what was the sollution? Same problem here...

Comment: Try to add 'ini_set('display_errors', 1);' to bin/magento. Maybe you'll see some helpfull outputs.

Comment: You should actually check error_log file on magento root which will give out errors for cli runtime errors.

It was memory shortfall for me.

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: Hi @MohitRane 
I never was able to reproduce the issue but at that time, no other information was available. A super strange issue that was solved after an upgrade or a change of environment (I don't remember right now)

Comment: You can try command line like this: php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 4):

It indicates that the error is being triggered while executing the command but for some reason, the view is disabled to read.

Luckily, all errors of Command is getting recorded in "error_log" file situated at the root, open it and read you error to fix this on the permanent basis.

Thank You
Zuber

Answer (score 3):

Open bin/magento in your preferred file editor and add the following line and save:

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);  // allow PHP errors reporting`
Run the command again:

`php  bin/magento  list`

it will show error which the cause cli not run

Answer (score -5):

Just `bin/magento` command will not work.

You can use commands like

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Make sure you current directroy in you magento instance ( cd /var/www/magento/)

For more command [reference's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125245/is-there-a-list-of-most-popular-cli-commands-for-magento-2).

Comment: That isn't the problem. No matter in which way I execute the command, the result is the same.
Also, you can run CLI commands with bin/magento because the file has the SheBang ( https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/bin/magento )

Comment: Ok fine, Make sure your php is running fine. type 'where is php', then you can get path like D:/something/php.exe... Then make the current directory in the exe (cd D:/something/php.exe /var/www/myapplication/bin/magento setup:upgrade. ) execute like.

Comment: If you execute `bin/magento` then it shows the list of available commands, so even this should work.